# Solr-solrj 4.9.0 run on jdk 1.6?

Tags: java, solr, java-6

Can Solr 4.9.0 solr-solrj API run in Java 1.6? (It seems to be compiled into Java 1.7)
I'm using solr server 4.9.0 and It needs Java 1.7 but I want use the client into my project and it's compiled on Java 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solr 4.9.0 has been compiled for java7. The last version I found compiled for java6 is 4.7.2. You can see this in the [pom.xml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.7.2/pom_effective)<sup>broken link</sup> for the project (relevant part reproduced below).

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning (perhaps obvious to some), the solrj 4.7.2 client is compatible with solr 4.9.0 servers. See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#SolrJ.2FSolr_cross-version_compatibility